# How to use Chebyshev Inequality

Tags: probability, inequality, normal-distribution

Use Chebyshev Inequality to estimate the probability that in any one day of a business that earns a mean of 100 dollars a day with a standard deviation of 28.87 dollars, that business will make either less than 60 dollars or more than 140 dollars.

$$\mu = 100,\quad \theta=28.87$$

$$P(|X-\mu| \ge d) \le \frac{\theta^2}{d^2}$$

$$X\sim N(100, 28.87^2)$$

$$\theta = 28.87\text{ and }d = 40$$

I understand everything up until $d = 40$. How does one obtain $d$?

Comment: Chebyshev is a very gross probability.  Usually, if you have a distribution for which you know the function and parameters, you'll find that the actual probability is very much less than the one guaranteed by Chebyshev.  For what it's worth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have
$$
|X-\mu| \ge d.
$$
That's the same as saying
$$
X-\mu \ge d\text{ or }X-\mu\le-d,
$$
(**"or", not "and"**) which is in turn equivalent to
$$
X\ge\mu+d\text{ or }X\le\mu-d.
$$
So you have $\mu+d=140$ and $\mu-d=60$ and $\mu=100$.

If $d=40$ and $\theta=28.87$ then $\dfrac{\theta^2}{d^2}=\text{a certain number}$.  That's all you need to answer your question.

But if you know it's normally distributed, you can get far more accurate values for this probability.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't clarify my question. Why does d = 40 instead of d =-40? (Also can d be negative?)

Comment: @Chase That is because you are taking the `abs` of the function. So no not really, `d` can't be negative.

Answer (score 2):

$$100-60=40$$
and
$$140-100=40$$

Comment: Why 100 - 60 and not 60 - 100?

Comment: $|140-100|=40$ and $|60-100|=40$ if you prefer